# onmouse out not working as needed

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I've been trying to do is that I have a box, that contains text obviously and I want that whenever it is hovered, to remove the current content and add another one and when it hovered out, to get back the old one. And my attempts as you realise are not going very well, I would like to know what's the exacy problem.
Thanks in advance.

```js
var i1,span1,a1,p1;
function changeContent1() {
    var item = document.getElementById('item1');
    var i = document.getElementById('icon1');
    var span = document.getElementById('itemSpan1');
    i1 = i;
    span1 = span;
    item.removeChild(i);
    item.removeChild(span);
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var t = document.createTextNode("The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem");
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "#";
    p1 = p;
    a1 = a;
    var at = document.createTextNode("Read More");
    p.appendChild(t);
    a.appendChild(at);
    item.appendChild(p);
    item.appendChild(a);
    item.style.background = "#ff3f3f";
    item.style.padding = '0';
}

function resetContent1() {
    var item = document.getElementById('item1');
    item.removeChild(a1);
    item.removeChild(p1);
    item.appendChild(i1);
    item.appendChild(span1);
}
```

```css
.item {
    width:270px;
    height:270px;
    margin-left:40px;
    float:left;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    text-align:center;
    padding:100px 0;
}

.item i{
    font-size:3em;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.item span {
    font-family:OpenSans-Bold;
    font-size:1.5em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" id="item1" onmouseover="changeContent1()" onmouseout="resetContent1()">
               <i class="fa fa-camera" id="icon1"></i><br />
               <span id="itemSpan1">Some text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do that only with `html` and `css`. If you want do container with 2 inner `div`s for each text. Hide the second. On hover hide first and show second. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zfm1cjgz/

Comment: Right, right. Thanks, don't know how that didn't occur to me. lots of thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You ca do it only with `html` and `css`.
Use `container` and 2 `div`s for texts inside and hide the second. On `hove` hide the first and show the second.

[**jsFiddel**](http://jsfiddle.net/zfm1cjgz/)